# Less Than operator not operating correctly

Tags: python

The less than operator is not working correctly for me:

```
port = raw_input("Enter Port: ")
        if port <= 65535:
            print("Valid Port")
        else:
            print("Port Invalid")
```

<strike>However, whenever I type in a port from 66 to 99 in ANY ten or hundred for example 166 or 766 or 889 it will be invalid, but anything below will be fine. It is like it is only registering/seeing the "65" part. I have tried without the `""` around the 65535 but that always returns invalid.</strike>

Alright, got it sorted, I did not know that it returned as a string. Although, I am kind of disappointed that I was ripped apart because of this and I am not up to the "high brow" standards of all of the people with years of experience.

Comment: Why on earth are you comparing the strings?

Comment: It might be answered in this. Raw input doesn't interpret and is bringing it in as a string perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python

Comment: I said about it not working with ""

Comment: the return value of `raw_input` still is a string.

Comment: @timgeb Ah right, I did not know that.

Comment: @BittenFleax Please try to ignore rude people, and don't let them put you off asking more questions in the future. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

You are comparing lexicographically. You should cast your input to a number, and compare it to a number as well:

```
port = int(raw_input("Enter Port: "))
if port <= 65535:
    print("Valid Port")
else:
    print("Port Invalid")
```

---

Consider also that, in Python 2, you can use the `input()` function to read integers instead of `raw_input()`. The behavior will be equivalent to `eval(raw_input())` so it will return an integer if the user types an integer, a float if the user types a float, and so on.

However, keep in mind that Python 3 removes both functions and replaces them with a single `input()` function that works like Python 2's `raw_input()`. So, I suggest to use `int(raw_input())` over `input()` because it will be easier to port to Python 3, and also because ["Explicit is better than implicit"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to compare the integer, and not the string.
e.g convert the string to integer before doing a comparision:

```
if int(port) <= 65535:
  print("Valid Port")
else:
  print("Port Invalid")
```